# How can I have text before a expression SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, textbox, expression

I need to be able to have the textbox within the table say " No. Of Tickets: " and then have the expression *=Count(Fields!TicketID.Value)* So that it is more user friendly because it wont just show a random number in the textbox.(P.S: this is going to be exported to excel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should solve your Issue

="No. of Tickets: " & Count(Fields!TicketID.Value)

Comment: Yesss! Thank you ! I am new to reporting services and I could not find any helpful information on how to do it. Thank you so much!